# REGEX_REPLACE is not working spark, hive and scala as expected

Tags: regex, scala, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala

I have a string `AF1234` and I want to print `1234` , also sometimes I get only numbers like `25` and `23` and I want these numbers as well, hence I am trying to use a regex_replace to check the string, below is the syntax:

```
select substring(nvl(nullif(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('AF1234','A$',''),'[[:digit:]]',''),''),'XX'),1,2)
```

This works in impala but not hive

Comment: add sample input and output to get more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Hive, Impala, Spark SQL

```
select regexp_extract('AF1234','(\\d+)',1)
```

Result:

```
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want numbers out of alphanumeric try this,

```
scala> spark.sql("select regexp_replace('AF1234','[A-Z]*','')").show
+------------------------------+
|regexp_replace(AF1234, [A-Z]*, )|
+------------------------------+
|                          1234|
+------------------------------+

spark.sql("select regexp_replace('23','[A-Z]*','')").show
+----------------------------+
|regexp_replace(23, [A-Z]*, )|
+----------------------------+
|                          23|
+----------------------------+
```